# Bitwise Operations and the Naming Convention of their Operators

Tags: operator-theory, computer-science, binary

So I just recently came across a [bitwise operation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Unsigned_right_shift) on StackOverflow which shifts the bits in a binary number to the right while zero-filling from the left.  The left side zero-filling overwrites the [sign bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_bit), thus it always yields positive representations of a number (the result cannot be negative).

E.g.:

**11010101 >>> 3**

yields

**00011010**

According to the normal mathematical conventions for naming operators, would it be correct to call this an *unsigned* bitshift operator?  I ask because it seems that this is not inherently an *unsigned* bitshift but just a zero-filling shift that overwrites (i.e. does not propagate) the sign bit. So, basically, it seems like although the *result* will always be *unsigned* it does not seem semantically correct to call the *operator* an *unsigned* bitshift operator.   Another [lemma??] which I've run into that further supports the argument that this operator should not be called *unsigned* is that it can be used on both signed and unsigned operands.

Comment: It sometimes fill ones from the right if there was a 1 in the signed bit and sometimes it fills zeros, it's system dependant (at least in C). Also, AFAIK, it's called bit shift (to the right) operator (C again).

Comment: Yeah that makes sense to me to call it bit shift (to the right).  The documentation I linked to seems to also [correctly?] call it a "zero-fill right shift" operator.  The main reason I asked the question is that I've found it in certain documentation where it is referred to as the [unsigned right shift](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.7.3) operator.

Answer (score 0):

Both $0$-filling and $1$-filling cases are referred to as bitshift operations. Calling the former an *unsigned bitshift operator* is ambiguous, as it is unclear what *unsigned* applies to (is it the bit, the bitshift, or the operator?).

If you want to make the description of the operator as unambiguous as possible, just use "*unsigned bit-filling bitshift operator*".